# How to make multidimentional array in php and smarty

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
 $a = array("008_@@_1_@@_Interieur_@@_1_@@_Inner-Bags",  "008_@@_1_@@_Interieur_@@_2_@@_Color", "008_@@_1_@@_Interieur_@@_3_@@_Material");`
```

and i use the explode function with *@@* explode this. and i get the array like this..

```
[0] => 008 
[1] => 1 
[2] => Interieur
[3] => 1 
[4] => Inner-Bags
```

and so on.

So i want the type of format array.

```
array('008' => array( '1' => array('Interieur' => array('1' => 'Inner-Bags', '2' => 'Color', '3' => 'Material'))));
```

This is my logic...

```
<?php
$a = array("008_@@_1_@@_Interieur_@@_1_@@_Inner-Bags", "008_@@_1_@@_Interieur_@@_2_@@_Color", "008_@@_1_@@_Interieur_@@_3_@@_Material");
$i = 0;
echo '<pre>';
$innerD = array();
foreach($a as $key => $val) {
 $innerA = array();
 $a_exploded = explode("_@@_", $a[$key]);
 $innerA[$a_exploded[3]] = $a_exploded[4];
}

foreach($a as $key => $val) {
    //print_r($a[$key]);
 $innerB = array();
 $innerC = array();
 $a_exploded = explode("_@@_", $a[$key]);

// print_r($innerA);

 $innerB[$a_exploded[2]] = $innerA;
 $innerC[$a_exploded[1]] = $innerB;
 $innerD[$a_exploded[0]] = $innerC;
}
print_r($innerD);
?>
```

i have use my logic but i din't get it the proper array like this..

```
Array
(
    [008] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Interieur] => Array
                        (
                            [3] => Material
                        )
                )    
        )    
)
```

and i want to array this format like this..

```
Array
(
    [008] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Interieur] => Array
                        (
                              [1] => Inner-Bags
                              [2] => Material
                              [3] => Color
                        )    
                )    
        )    
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$a = array("008_@@_1_@@_Interieur_@@_1_@@_Inner-Bags", "008_@@_1_@@_Interieur_@@_2_@@_Color", "008_@@_1_@@_Interieur_@@_3_@@_Material");
$i = 0;
echo '<pre>';
$innerD = array();
foreach($a as $val){
  $a_exploded = explode("_@@_", $val);
  $innerD[$a_exploded[0]][$a_exploded[1]][$a_exploded[2]][] = $a_exploded[3];
}
print_r($innerD);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you reset array inside first `foreach`.

Change

```
foreach($a as $key => $val) {
    $innerA = array(); // <-- it is wrong string. remove it.
    $a_exploded = explode("_@@_", $a[$key]);
    $innerA[$a_exploded[3]] = $a_exploded[4];
}
```

to:

```
foreach($a as $key => $val) {
    $a_exploded = explode("_@@_", $a[$key]);
    $innerA[$a_exploded[3]] = $a_exploded[4];
}
```